# Can I use CustomControl's Template's named controls in a UserControl like style?

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

We previously used `UserControls`, which have been transformed into `CustomControls` now.
The `UserControls` usually had named inner controls, which could be reached from the code behind.
Now we have problems reaching the named inner controls of the CustomControls' ControlTemplate.

Demonstrating example:

**ControlTemplate of CustomControl:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:CustomControl1}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:CustomControl1}">
                <Grid x:Name="PART_GridRoot" >
                    <!-- ... -->
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**"Code behind" of CustomControl:**

```
static CustomControl1()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1)));
}

private Grid _gridRoot;

public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    _gridRoot = (Grid)this.Template.FindName("PART_GridRoot", this);;
}

public void Foo()
{
    _gridRoot.Foo(); // Null reference exception if calling in too early state
}
```

The problem is the default `ControlTemplate` gets assigned (into `CustomControl1.Template`) too lately. It does not get applied in `ctor`, nor if calling `ApplyTemplate` or Measure manually.

Is there a way to make the default `ControlTemplate` get assigned earlier?
Am I supposed to be able to use CustomControls' Template's named controls in this UserControl like style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could hasten the assignment of the `Template` (and actually, the default `Style`). 
This way:

```
public class MyControl : Control
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        ApplyDefaultStyle();
    }

    protected void ApplyDefaultStyle()
    {
        this.Style = WpfHelpers.GetDefaultStyle(this.GetType(), "OwnResourceDictionaryFullPath here");
        this.ApplyTemplate();
    }
}

public static class WpfHelpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extracts the control's default Style from the resource dictionary pointed by the <see cref="resourceFullPath"/>.
    /// So the Style without x:Key, with TargetType <see cref="controlType"/>
    /// </summary>
    public static Style GetDefaultStyle(Type controlType, string resourceFullPath)
    {
        Uri resourceLocater = null;
        string assemblyName = null;
        try
        {
            assemblyName = controlType.Assembly.GetName().Name;
            resourceLocater = new Uri($"/{assemblyName};component/{resourceFullPath}", UriKind.Relative);
            var resourceDictionary = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(resourceLocater);
            var style = resourceDictionary[controlType] as Style;
            return style;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Log.Warn
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

So I assign the default `Style` manually. 
I know I've lost automatic theming possibilities this way, but I can live with that. 
I can just hope this solution does not have disadvantages, like performance issues. It seems very similar for me to `UserControl`'s `InitializeComponent()` call.

Answer (score 1):

`OnApplyTemplate` is called after the template has been applied. Prior to that time, there is no way to get hold of your named inner controls, as they haven't yet been created.

Which means fields like `_gridRoot` can only be accessed after `OnApplyTemplate` has been called. In places that might be reachable both before and after, if any, you could check for `null`.

Comment: Still, is there a way to urge the Template assignment?  
Would it be a good practise to apply it manually maybe?

Comment: Sorry, no. `OnApplyTemplate` is called first thing after the template has been applied; it is your earliest opportunity to do anything.

Comment: Sorry, but no. I hopefully wait for an aswer of a trick, or somethig. Hard to believe I'm the only person who has this problem/misunderstanding of the CustomControls... Anyway, thank you for answering, I gave +1

Comment: Maybe, if instead of overriding the DefaultStyleKeyProperty, we could set a Template manually in ctor - would that work? Would it be a good practise? Would it have similar effect like InitializeCompontent in a UserControl?